# Angular ui-router initial state without URL

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Using UIRouter in an Angular 1.5 app, I'm having trouble trying to set an initial state for my angular module.

I've created a few states without URLs (because I don't need actual routing) and I would like to activate an initial state once the module is instantiated.

Usually, I would do this using `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(<initialRoute>)`, but since I don't use URLs in my states, that can't work.

Does UIRouter (or Angular) provide a solution for this?

Comment: sorry but if you don't have route ..why di you want to set one? .. have you tried already $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/') and set <base ref="/"> in your index?

Comment: No I don't have any route, juste states without URLs. It's actually a feature of UIRouter, you can activate such a state the same way as for a routed state (using `ui-sref` or `$state.go()` for example). Similarly to a routed application where you usually define a default URL (such as /home for example), I would like to have a default state (that is not URL-based). Is that clearer?

Comment: but ui-sref and $state.go are used to navigate to a url .. but ok

Comment: I know, it looks weird but it is intended to work like that :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After your application has bootstrapped, you can set your initial state  inside the `.run()` method.

```
angular.module("myModuleName")
    .run([
        "$state",
         function($state){
            $state.go('stateName');
         }
     ]);
```

Comment: Thank you, it works well! Indeed, it makes perfect sense and that's a clean solution :)